# How to calculate quoted spread in pandas for each day?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have a data of bond market like this:

```
Id   row      Date       BuyPrice    SellPrice    Time
1    1      2017-10-30    94520       0          9:00:00
1    2      2017-10-30    94538       0          9:00:00
1    3      2017-10-30    94609       0          9:00:00
1    4      2017-10-30    94615       0          9:00:00
1    5      2017-10-30    94617       0          9:00:00
1    1      2017-09-20    99100       99159      9:00:10
1    2      2017-09-20    99102       99058      9:00:11
1    3      2017-09-20    99103       99057      9:00:12
1    4      2017-09-20    99104       99056      9:00:10
1    5      2017-09-20    99105       99055      9:00:10
1    1      2017-09-20    98100       99190      9:01:10
1    2      2017-09-20    98099       99091      9:01:10
1    3      2017-09-20    98098       99092      9:01:10
1    4      2017-09-20    98097       99093      9:01:10
1    5      2017-09-20    98096       99094      9:01:10
2    1      2010-11-01    99890       100000     10:00:02
2    2      2010-11-01    99899       100000     10:00:02
2    3      2010-11-01    99901       99899      9:00:02
2    4      2010-11-01    99920       99850      10:00:02
2    5      2010-11-01    99933       99848      10:00:23
```

Step 1:

I want to calculate  the spread(=SellPrice - BuyPrice) for row number one for each id for each day and exclude zeros if there is a zero in BuyPrice or SellPrice(Report nan for this kind of data), data in this step should be like this:

```
id     row      Date         BuyPrice      SellPrice     Spread
1      1        2017-10-30   94520         0             NaN
1      1        2017-09-20   99100         99159         59
1      1        2017-09-20   98100         99190         190
2      1        2010-11-01   99890         100000        110
```

Step 2:

Now i want to calculate average of Spread for each day for each id and give index respect to date

At last data should be like this:

```
Id    Date        avg.spread(average of spread for each day)   index
1     2017-10-30   NaN                                           1
1     2017-09-20   124.5(=(59+190)/2)                            2
2     2010-11-01   110                                           1
```

Comment: It seems like you are dropping duplicates. Can you confirm if your expected outputs are correct? Also, I'm getting different values for average than you for this data.

Comment: Also, it is not clear how this index is calculated and printed.

Comment: average is calculate like this: (59+90)/2 ,(and exclude NaN values for average and if for a day there is only NaN values report NaN).Index is number of days means for instant in this example; 2017-10-30 is the first day so it gets index 1 and 2017-09-20 is the second day for id 1 so it gets index 2

Comment: Yes but 99190 - 98100 is 1090.0, not 90. And in the last row where id = 2, it's 99890, not 99899.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried my best to understand what you want, although you haven't explicitly mentioned it, I think you want to `groupby` on `Id`, `row`, *and* `date`.

```
g = df.assign(diff=df.SellPrice.sub(df.BuyPrice))\
                 .groupby(['Id', 'row', 'Date']).diff.mean()

v = g.groupby(level=[0, 1]).cumcount().add(1).values
df = g.reset_index().assign(index=v)

df

    Id  row        Date   diff  index
0    1    1  2017-09-20  574.5      1
1    1    1  2017-10-30    NaN      2
2    1    2  2017-09-20  474.0      1
3    1    2  2017-10-30    NaN      2
4    1    3  2017-09-20  474.0      1
5    1    3  2017-10-30    NaN      2
6    1    4  2017-09-20  474.0      1
7    1    4  2017-10-30    NaN      2
8    1    5  2017-09-20  474.0      1
9    1    5  2017-10-30    NaN      2
10   2    1  2010-11-01  110.0      1
11   2    2  2010-11-01  101.0      1
12   2    3  2010-11-01   -2.0      1
13   2    4  2010-11-01  -70.0      1
14   2    5  2010-11-01  -85.0      1
```